# Did Obama secretly visit Antarctica?

Tags: barack-obama, antarctica

It has been suggested on some occult web sites and documentaries that [Obama secretly visited Antarctica](http://www.disclose.tv/news/obamas_secret_antarctica_tripoperation_highjump_russia__us/133310) as a side trip when visited Argentina earlier this year (March 2016).

Is this true?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, have any of those sites offered a plausible reason for Obama to keep such a visit a secret?  I think we can dismiss "to visit escaped Nazis living inside the hollow Earth" as not plausible :-)

Comment: The reason given is "the Nazis, and Hollow Earth, including its importance in Nazi Germany before and during WW2, and Antarctica's possible escape route off of the Earth for many Nazi's[sic]". Plausibility is not a requirement.

Comment: Should some of the detail from the linked [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319131831/https://www.disclose.tv/obamas-secret-antarctica-trip-operation-highjump-russia-us-311777) be copied into the question, even if the question isn't about them? All the talk of nazis and hollow earth would confuse me after link rot happens.

Answer (score 9):

In March 2016, [President Obama travelled to Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_presidential_trips_made_by_Barack_Obama#2016). The supposed Antarctic trip presumably is being claimed to have occurred on Thursday, March 24th, 2016, because that was when President Obama left Buenos Aires, Argentina to travel south.

[The press schedule published in advance](http://chicago.suntimes.com/columnists/obama-guidance-press-schedule-march-19-20-2016-off-to-cuba/) describes the schedule.

> On Thursday, the President will visit the Parque de la Memoria. In the afternoon, the First Family will depart Buenos Aires and travel to Bariloche, Argentina. The First Family will visit cultural landmarks while in Bariloche. In the evening, the First Family will depart Bariloche and return to Buenos Aires, Argentina. Later in the evening, the First Family will depart Argentina en route Washington, DC.

They were there.  This trip was known about in advance and there are pictures of them [arriving in Bariloche](https://theobamadiary.com/2016/03/24/the-first-family-in-bariloche/) and [meeting the Argentinian President](https://www.lapatilla.com/site/2016/03/24/la-estancia-de-obama-y-macri-en-bariloche-fotos/) on that day.

The conspiracy theory then relies on him somehow within that day vanishing from the public eye without notice so that he could take a flight to Antarctica.  A flight that would have taken [many hours](http://www.travelmath.com/flying-time/from/Argentina/to/Antarctica) each way.  Not to mention the time it would have taken for him to hike to this mysterious gateway. That is implausible.

Comment: Please provide references that (a) March *24th* was the day in question. (Was it in the video? I can't stomach watching that all the way through to check.) and (b) there are photos of the First Family in Bariloche, which your argument relies upon.

Comment: The week of the 21st is the only trip that Obama has ever taken to Argentina as President.

Comment: @Tal That information, along with some way to verify it, should be in the answer, not a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time for almost any reason, and should not be relied upon to remain.